# Should a while loop in run method of a Thread be stopped using isInterrupted() method

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it good practice to use isInterrupted() method of the Thread to end a while loop in its run method, by calling its interrupt() method from outside.

```
public class ThreadManager{
    ...
    ...
    Thread t;
    public void init(){
      t = new MyThread();
      t.start();
    }

    .....
    public void stopProcessing(){
      t.interrupt();
    }
}

public class MyThread extends Thread{

     public void run(){

           while( !isInterrupted()){
              try{
                  //.. some process in a loop
              }catch(InterruptedException e){
                 // now stop running and end run method
              }
           }


     }

}
```

Comment: According to the [Oracle-Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) on Interrupts, it is fine to use this mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I always used a volatile boolean for this purpose, which I declare as a class level variable and declare it volatile to avoid jvm to do any re ordering and always fetch the value of it from main memory. But if above approcah can be used then I guess no need of boolean flag :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically and in most cases, yes. It is a good practice to use `isInterrupted()` as a condition in while loop, but that's usually not all you need to do.

In many cases, you also need to catch `InterruptedException` which signals that `interrupt()` was called. One of these cases might be using of `Thread.sleep()` in the loop. If thread is sleeping or waiting, this exception must be caught. You can use for example `break` in the catch block.

```
public void run() {
    while(!isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            ...
            sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @James-Sorry, I, by mistake, removed `Long` sign. I heartily apologise for the same.

Comment: It's OK, these things happen all the time :)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably a matter of opinion.  In *my* opinion (and that's all it is), Yes, using interrupt as a means to signal a thread to shut down is a good idea.

I seldom ever get to write the top level of any application.  I write library code.  I always assume that `interrupt()` means that my code should gracefully abort whatever it was asked to do, but that it should be prepared in case the top-level application asks it to do something again afterward.

If my code creates a thread, and an interrupt happens in the thread, I "abort" by having the thread shut itself down, but I make sure that my code can re-create the thread if needed.

That way, if the designer of the top-level app wants `interrupt()` to mean, "shut down the application," my code will work with that; but if the designer of the top-level app wants it to mean something different (e.g., abort the current command, and prompt a user for another), then my code will work with that too.